# DQL get the list of default groups

Tags: documentum

Is there a way to get the list of default groups (owners,contributors,members) of a room using dql in `documentum 6.6`

Answer (score 1):

Besides

```
select builtin_groups from dmc_room where object_name ="MYROOM"
```

To list the room and there actual(owners and contributors only) groups use:-

```
select dg.group_name,dr.object_name from dm_group dg,dmc_room dr where group_name like 'room_%_%n%s' and dg.group_name IN dr.builtin_groups
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select builtin_groups from dmc_room where object_name ="MYROOM"
```